# Angular Router calling 2 routes

Tags: angular, routes

I'm using angular 4+ and i'm using the router. My issue is too large to post code but I'm just looking for clues as to where to start. I'll update the answer and question as I get more close to the actual issue.

When I use my app, I can route to all the pages fine but once I visit a specific page (call it "pageA"), anytime I route away from pageA to another page, pageA gets activated. I have no idea why but if I log the router events, It shows as routing to the correct page but pageA is still being activated.

I'm really not sure where to start. Any clues would be awesome! Thanks and sorry for not pasting code!

these are my two offending routes.

```
{path: 'narrative', component: NarrativeComponent},
{path: 'creator/:handle', component: CreatorsLandingComponent}
```

**EDIT I'm still getting the same issue as I was before but I'm solving this by using a service and setting the param that I need there, then I only access that and not the routing that is being changed.

Comment: Did you unsubscribe to the route subscription in ngOnDestroy?

Comment: I did not. I've not done that for any of my routes and have never run into that as an issue. I'm diving in now and will post if that solves it. Thank you so much for taking the time.

Comment: What do you mean with `gets activated`?

Comment: You need to put here your routes configurations, in order to identify the issue, in my experience, this can happen when the route to pageA can match in some way the route to pageB.

Comment: When I call pageA, all works. When I then navigate to pageB, pageA is called again. I can see it run it's ngOnInit and it overrides info on pageB. Question is edited.